# slidetoggle empty div should not work

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

```js
$('.cat').click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().text() == '') {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='themea cat'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='titlewrap'>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class='themea cat'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

`next` to `cat` is `titlewrap` and has no text. Still, click on `cat` is trying to `slideToggle` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim the string to avoid whitespace.

```js
$('.cat').click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().text().trim() == '') {
    return false;
  }
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='themea cat'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='titlewrap'>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class='themea cat'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: it works, but there is no whitespace inside `titlewrap` !

Comment: @bonaca : `<div class='titlewrap'><!-- here --><ul>
 </ul><!-- here --></div>`